# How do I properly set a infinite timeout on desktop notifications created by the browser

Tags: javascript, html, push-notification, notifications

I want to create desktop notifications using Notification api.My requirement is show desktop notification until user will close.The default timeout of the notification is 20 sec. only.I want to extend it more.

```
 var notification = new Notification('Notification');
 setTimeout(function() {
     notification.close()
 }, 40000);
```

The above script 40 seconds not working

Comment: You need to disable the internal timer somehow.

Comment: How can i disable?

Comment: This may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664740/how-do-i-make-a-notification-stay-open-until-the-user-closes-it

Comment: Thank q.It's working.:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a Notification stay open until the user closes it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664740/how-do-i-make-a-notification-stay-open-until-the-user-closes-it)

Answer (score 2):

To add some explanation to Jeremy Thille's comment:

This way you only can close the notifications earlier than the browser would do it by default. The default is browser-dependent (e.g. the Firefox I'm currently using seems to have a timeout of about 20 seconds whereas older versions only have about 4 seconds).

As stated in the comment, some modern browsers support the `requireInteraction` flag ([How do I make a Notification stay open until the user closes it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664740/how-do-i-make-a-notification-stay-open-until-the-user-closes-it)). This way you can make it appear longer than the default duration.